# How to stop random links from opening with react-router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am new to React and practicing with an online website for repairing appliances. I have used **react-router** and created all my routes in a separate file.

I have a problem though, I can open any link from the address bar like:

```
http://localhost:3000/<randomword>
```

I only want routes to be opened that I have declared in my routes component while if I type `http://localhost:3000/something`, I get an empty page with my header and footer in it.

here are my codes:

`Index.js`:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import Routes from './Routes';
import './index.css';

const App = () => {
    return(
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes />
        </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }

ReactDOM.render(<App/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

`App.js`:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import Layout from './Containers/Layout';
import LandingPage from './Containers/Pages/LandingPage';
import About from './Containers/Pages/About';
import Cities from './Containers/Pages/Cities';
import Discount from './Containers/Pages/Discount';


class Routes extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Layout>
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Route path="/" render={props => <LandingPage {...props} />} exact component={LandingPage}/>
                        <Route path="/About" component={About}/>
                        <Route path="/Cities" component={Cities}/>
                        <Route path="/Discount" component={Discount}/>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </Layout>
            </div>
    );
}
};

export default Routes;
```

`Layout.js`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Header from "./Layouts/Header";
import Footer from './Layouts/Footer';
import './Layout.css';

export default class Layout extends Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state= {
           
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="page-container">
                <Header/>
                    <div className="content-wrap">
                        {this.props.children}
                    </div>
                <Footer/>
            </div>);
        }
}
```

Can someone help me figure out how I should stop random random pages to be opened from addressbar?

Answer (score 0):

Just want to start by saying I'm completely self-taught with React so I apologize if this answer is incorrect. However, in my experience with react-router I always have a `Switch` inside of my `BrowserRouter`. So your Routes class in `app.js` should something like this:

```js
class Routes extends Component {
    render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Layout>
                    <BrowserRouter>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/" render={props => <LandingPage {...props} />} exact component={LandingPage}/>
                            <Route path="/About" component={About}/>
                            <Route path="/Cities" component={Cities}/>
                            <Route path="/Discount" component={Discount}/>
                        </Switch>
                    </BrowserRouter>
                </Layout>
            </div>
        );
    }
};
```

Just be sure you don't forget to update your imports to

```js
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import {  Redirect } from "react-router-dom"
<Route path="/not-found" component={notFound-Component} />
<Redirect to="/not-found" />
```

This will always redirect you to 404 component if route is not present just make a 404 component and u should add the redirect at the end after all routes are defined